# Is there a biological explanation for a 0.5 difference in allele size with PCR product?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, dna-sequencing, pcr, biodiversity

### CONTEXT

---

I am currently working on a set of diversity, this diversity in interspecific (within the same genus). I am using SSR markers, the primers were designed on one species and are working really well within the species (lot of diversity and difference between allele of 1 at least).
When trying them on the other species, I observe the normal non-amplification which could be due to mutation in the primer DNA sequence. But, for some genotypes I have been observing a new allele just between the two older ones (like the new one is 185.5 and the olders were 185 and 186.

### QUESTIONS

---

Is that kind of observation frequent when using primers designed on other species?
I understand how a 1 pb difference could occur `CACACA` ==> `CACCACA`, but what could the biological explanations be for a 0.5 pb difference between alleles?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, working with a similar approach in *Campylobacter jejuni*, the base pair measurements from these techniques are imprecise and need to be carefully calibrated. I am unsurprised to see 0.5 base pair differences, this can be seen been runs and even, in the worse case situation, between even and odd wells in the same plate(!).

I would use Sanger sequencing to determine the sequence you are getting in one of your isolates, and then use this as a calibration control included in every run.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I was planning to do a sanger sequencing to understand the problem. The allele though is quite stable (same length on different plates). Usually I see all my alleles in a 0.5 pb variation around the real value depending on genotypes/runs.

Comment: @Untitpoi We found that different length targets from the same strain, and the same targets from different strains frequently gave different length results.

Comment: @Untitpoi I think it occurs because of differences in the sequence causing sligtht differences in mobility during capillary electrophoresis. If you look at the raw data from a sequencing read, you can see that the peaks appear less regularly than the smoothed processed peak data you usually look at. I would guess there are consistent differences in the progress of sequences based on the physical properties of the nucleotides.